# ModalPopupExtender positioning in small, positioned container

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I've got a `ModalPopupExtender` on an ASP.NET 4.0 page that's contained in a thin `div` (200px wide) that is absolutely positioned near one side of the window.  This throws off the positioning and width of the modal when it comes up, because it's positioned with `position:absolute`, which ends up being relative to the small container in this case.  So when it comes up, it's far to one side of the page and very thin.

What is the best way to make it relative to another control?  Should I use javascript (perhaps jQuery) to remove the popup and append it to some other element on the page that would yield better positioning for its relative-positioned children?  Or is there a way to configure the popup differently?